# Caching virtual function calls in C++

Tags: c++, performance, caching, virtual-functions

Is there a way to cache the virtual function calls. Virtual function call may not be a performance bottle neck. But as a thought experiment, if we 'cache' the virtual function call, will it improve performance or make it worse?

```
class B {
public:
    virtual int func(int a) = 0;
};

class D1 : public B {
public:
    int func(int a)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

typedef std::function<int(int)> func_type;
func_type  gv;

template <typename T>
void addFuncCache(B *b)
{
    func_type f = [=] (int a) ->int {
        return static_cast<T *>(b)->T::func(a);
    };

    gv = f;
}

int main()
{
    D1 d1;

    addFuncCache<D1>(&d1);
    gv(10);   
}
```

here call to

```
gv(10);
```

any faster than

```
B *bp = &d1; bp->func(10);
```

Or is it worse.

Comment: Well, you can time it to find out.

Comment: You have achieved nothing. A `std::function` call requires an indirect call (or virtual call) behind the scenes anyway. Also, the answer to "will it improve/worsen performance" is: measure.

Comment: I cannot see that being faster.  Full on `void*` and `int(*)(void*,int)` style type erasure with a `final`non the derived class *might* be.  But even there you'd be getting in the way of the compiler optimizing, especially when you bring in global state.  In practice, I cannot see it being a good idea.

Comment: What are you caching exactly when you "cache a virtual function"?

Comment: In some cases, compiler can devirtualize the virtual function call.

Comment: So, replace looking the function up in the object's vtable with looking the function up in  a cache? Probably a net loss.